# Excel VBA Copy Paste Values only

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a file which can transfer data on a daily basis from one sheet to another. I can get the transfer of data but it copies over the formulas too and all the cells gives a *ref error*. How can I copy over only the values and not the formulas. I'm new to VBA and any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Tried to use the `PasteSpecial` code but will not work.

```vb
Sub Number1()
'
' Number1 Macro
'
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Copy of PLA Failure Results (Macro) Good Test 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Data")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Copy of PLA Failure Results (Macro) Good Test 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Stored Data")

  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


  wsCopy.Range("J2:R" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("A2" & lDestLastRow)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change:**

```
wsCopy.Range("J2:R" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("A2" & lDestLastRow)
```

**With:**

```
wsCopy.Range("J2:R" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

You can Use `PasteSpecial` for that, and also you are using `A2` and lastrow which is Wrong, it should be `A` & Lastrow

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to clean up your code. Declare your workbook once and then you can reference throughout at a later stage, is needed. Additionally I think your error is happening in your `Paste` line. See below code (not tested):

```vb
Sub Number1()

    Dim wbGood As Workbook
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long

    Set wbGood = Workbooks("Copy of PLA Failure Results (Macro) Good Test 2.xlsm")

    Set wsCopy = wbGood.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set wsDest = wbGood.Worksheets("Stored Data")

    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wsCopy.Range("J2:R" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `.Copy` in this case. You can just assign the `.Value` of the destination range to be equal to the value of the copy range, **and this is faster than copying**:

```
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow & ":I" & lDestLastRow + lCopyLastRow - 2).Value = _
             wsCopy.Range("J2:R" & lCopyLastRow).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

xlPasteValues didn't work for me for some reason. But the following change worked.

wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial -4163